# Vuforia-Unity, How To Move Animated Objects When Marker is Outside Camera View?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

We would like to move our animated object independently from frame marker or target image even they are not visible by camera; after initial setup.

However when we run our application, our model appears on target image or frame marker but as soon as marker or target is out of camera; the animated image disappears too.

How can we keep our model animating or moving around when frame marker or image target is outside camera view?

Note: We are using UNITY 3D.

Comment: You want the object to be seen at all time so what is the purpose of Vuforia in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

All objects that are not under rendering camera are automatically deactivated in Vuforia logic. You just have to override this property and make them active so they can continue their animation and movement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please which function i need to override and how i can do it?

Comment: You don't need to override functions, just set the object.active = true. AFAIK, there must be a layer where objects are not set unactive